# How to route DetailView to inherit user and slug

Tags: django

I have a fairly simple DetailView:

```
class TrackDetails(DetailView):
    model = Track
```

And in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', TrackDetails.as_view(), name='track-details'),
```

The model:

```
class Track(models.Model):

    ....


    # Variables

    track_type_choices = [
        ('ORG', 'Original'),
        ('RMX', 'Remix'),
        ('CLB', 'Collab'),
        ('LIV', 'Live'),
    ]

    # Model Fields
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=7500)
    track_type = models.CharField(max_length=3,
                                 choices=track_type_choices,
                                 default='ORG')

    track_type_content = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    created = models.TimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)

    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_user_folder_tracks,storage=OverwriteStorage(),validators=[is_mp3])
    albumart = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_user_folder_art,storage=OverwriteStorage(),validators=[is_square_png])
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    downloadable = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likes",blank=True)
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="dislikes",blank=True)
    plays = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True)
```

The model displayed in the view has a "user" field connected to the user model, I want to use this in the url, so that instead of writing "www.domain.com/slug/" I would write "www.domain.com/user/slug" to access the view of the instance.

**Additionally**, I have extended the User model with a field called "Display_name", I'd like to show this field instead of the username in my template (track_detail.html):

```
{% include '__header.html' %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<div id="track_container">
    <div id="track_titleinfo">
        <div id="track_artist" class="text">{{ object.user }}</div>
        <div id="track_title" class="text">{{ object.title }}</div>
        {% if object.track_type == 'ORG' %}
        {% else %}
        <div id="track_type" class="text">({{object.track_type_content}})</div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% include '__footer.html' %}
<img src="/static/users/{{ object.user }}/art/{{ object.slug }}.png" alt="">
```

The div with the ID "track_artist" displays the raw username (In this case, enitoni), I'd like it to display the display_name (In this case "Ekchö") from the userprofile class of the user who owns the Track instance:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="null")

    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include the username in the detail view, you first need to add it to your url patterns.

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', TrackDetails.as_view(), name='track-details'),
```

Then, since you are using `DetailView`, you need to override `get_object` so that you use the username and slug to fetch the object.

```
from django.shortcuts imporg get_object_or_404

class TrackDetails(DetailView):
    model = Track

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(
            Track, 
            user__username=self.kwargs['username'],
            slug=self.kwargs['slug'],,
        )
```

Displaying the `display_name` of the user in the template is a separate problem. If you have a `user`, you can follow the one to one key backwards to the profile with `user.userprofile`. Therefore, in your template you can show the `display_name` with.

```
{{ object.user.userprofile.display_name }}
```

Comment: That solved my display_name issue, however I am now getting this error when trying to access the track [Pastebin](http://.pastebin.com/hRCFXt2h)

Comment: Oops, it should be `self.kwargs['username ']` to match the url.

Comment: I'm still getting an error, now it is saying that "slug" is not defined. See: http://dpaste.com/1G6QHK5

Comment: It should be `slug=self.kwargs['slug']`.

Comment: Oh my god you are a lifesaver! Thank you thank you thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

To access `username` and `slug` first pass in the two keywords:

```
url(r'^/(?P<username>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', get_userpage, name='track-details'),
```

Then check if `Track.objects.filter(slug=slug, username=username)` returns anything:

```
def get_userpage(request, username, slug):
   """Render user page"""
   user = User.objects.get(username=username)
   track_song = Track.objects.filter(slug=trackslug, user=user).first() 
   if track_song:
       # return song page for user

   else:
      # try to return user
      track_user = Track.objects.filter(user=user).first() 
      if track_user:
          # return user page

   # if nothing returned above 
   # return 404
```

---

Previous suggestions:

- you can you use `get_object_or_404(Track, slug=slug)` in your view to return the correct response.
- you could also redirect a user to their unique combination of username and slug using:

  redirect('track-username-slug', username=myusername slug=myslug, permanent=True)

where `track-username-slug` is your named url

Comment: I want the username, not the user ID

Comment: I don't fully understand your use case but it seems like use a combination of  url keywords and redirects you can get to anywhere you want on the site

Comment: Sorry, let me explain it a bit better. Every "Track" instance has a User field which is the user who "uploaded" the track or the "artist" if you will, I want django to only access the track if it finds that user associated with it. So for example if "user1" has not uploaded any tracks, then "/user1/trackslug" would return a 404, but if user1 did actually upload a track, then access that track. Even if "trackslug" exists from any other Track instance, django will only retrieve it if the user specified has it.

Comment: ok, I think I'm understanding it a little better. So if `Track.objects.filter(slug=trackslug, user=user)` returns something, you want to return that page?

Comment: Yeah! Kinda like how soundcloud does it, as a comparison. You type the user you want, then the name of the track you want to listen to. For example /user/track1.

Comment: Revised my initial answer - will join chat briefly